# C++ casting pointer to pointers (x**) -> (y**)

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am fairly new to C++ and I decided to do some experimenting with pointers to pointers.  I am trying to create a system where I can use and abstract class to define an interface that many unrelated classes can inherit (often via multiple inheritance) so that I can then shove them off to some common helper functions.

I have boiled the code down about as much as I can so I apologize if the listing is a bit long...

```
//------------ HEADER

struct IClassData
{
    virtual int Width() = 0;
    virtual int Height() = 0;
};

class ClassA
{
    public:
        ClassA(int w, int h);

        protected:
            int _Width;
            int _Height;
};


class Derived : public ClassA, public IClassData
{
    public:
        Derived();
        Derived(int w, int h);

    virtual int Width() override;
    virtual int Height() override;
};

class Computron
{
public:
    static int TotalWidth(IClassData** data, int size)
    {
        int curSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            curSum += data[i]->Width();
        }

        return curSum;
    }
};

// -------------- CPP
ClassA::ClassA(int w, int h)
{
    _Width= w;
    _Height = h;
}

Derived::Derived() : ClassA(0,0) { /* NONE */ } 
Derived::Derived(int w, int h) : ClassA(w,h) { /* NONE */ } 

int Derived::Width() { return _Width; }
int Derived::Height() { return _Height; }
```

So in my main program I am creating a number of instances of the derived class, and I want to do some casting so that it can work against the computron functions like so:

```
// --------------- MAIN

...
const int MAX = 5;
    Derived** data = new Derived*[MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        data[i] = new Derived(i, i*2);
    }

    // Cast an compute
    int size = Computron::TotalWidth((IClassData**)data, MAX);
...
```

So my big questions are:
  1. Is this an OK thing to do, or will I be shooting myself in the foot later?  I realize that my classes are very simple here, but if they were to get very complex would that cause some problems down the line?
  2. Also, is there a chance that a cast like this might not work at runtime for some reason?
  3. Am I better off just using a template for these types of scenarios?

Comment: _"**Is this** an OK thing to do, or will I be shooting myself in the foot later?"_ Is what in particular? Can you elaborate more about, on particular doubts on your design, or at least give a concise code sample reproducing your issues?

Comment: If you don't have really good reasons, you shouldn't use pure interfaces. You know we have templates?

Comment: `Derived** data = new Derived*[MAX]` <- Are you trying to declare an array here? I do mostly C# these days but I'm pretty sure that won't compile. What is the asterisk for before `[MAX]`?

Comment: @JonathanWood This allocates an array of `MAX` elements, where each element is a `Derived *` (pointer-to-`Derived`). The result of this allocation is a `Derived **` (pointer-to-pointer-to-`Derived`).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an OK thing to do, or will I be shooting myself in the foot later? I realize that my classes are very simple here, but if they were to get very complex would that cause some problems down the line?

I don't see anything here that screams trouble *generally*, but I would strongly suggest using the standard library to avoid memory management problems later.  For example, instead of your array I would use:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Derived>> data;
```

When `data` goes out of scope, the vector will be destroyed.  This in turn will cause the unique_ptr's to be destroyed, and they will automatically delete the `Derived` objects.

However, you only need pointers where you need to be polymorphic and store different types of objects in the same array; that is, you'd be more likely to need this if you are storing pointers to `IClassData` objects, where you don't know exactly what derived type is going to appear in the array at runtime.  As written, you can simply use an `std::vector<Derived>` because you know that all of the objects will be `Derived` instances.

> Also, is there a chance that a cast like this might not work at runtime for some reason?

Don't use C-style casts in C++. You should be using `static_cast` here, and *[it doesn't even work at compile time](http://ideone.com/Jvnxvh)* because it violates the type system.

```
Derived ** a = new Derived*[MAX];
Base ** b = static_cast<Base **>(a); // This line will not compile, because...

b[0] = new Base();           // Now a[0] is a Base rather than a Derived??
a[0]->some_derived_method(); // What should happen!?!?
```

> Am I better off just using a template for these types of scenarios?

Each scenario is different, so the answer is a definitive "maybe."

Comment: Do note that `unique_ptr` requires C++11 or later. In earlier versions, there was only `auto_ptr`, which is not safe to use in STL containers (one of the reasons why `unique_ptr` was created to replace `auto_ptr`).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for advice on memory management.  Yes, if I had a single case where I was only using derived, I would that.  I am asking about multiple unknown types that may use IClassData and can therefore be sent to the utility function mentioned.

Comment: @A.R. The utility function is fine, but you have to actually start with an array of `IClassData*`. You can't cast a pointer-to-pointer to a different element type.

Comment: @A.R. Because you are using a C-style cast, which is basically the equivalent of `reinterpret_cast` in this case -- it's undefined behavior, and working as you intended is one of the (many) possible outcomes. Try it on a different compiler or a different version of the same compiler and it very well might crash at runtime. This is why you never use C-style casts in C++; `reinterpret_cast` is *very* dangerous, and with a C-style cast you can get that behavior without trying to. (See [this article](https://anteru.net/2007/12/18/200/) regarding what C-style casts do in C++.)

Comment: It likely works in your case because `Derived` doesn't introduce any new virtual functions, and so the vtables either overlap exactly in memory, or they are simply equivalent for both classes, and so it behaves correctly when you use a pointer to the wrong one. If the compiler made a different decision then it's likely that your code would blow up at runtime. Bottom line: undefined behavior is bad. Don't invoke it, even if it appears to work right now -- it might not work later.

Comment: OK, great.  This is more like the answer that I am looking for.